# Pyspark Dataframe Compare

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, compare

I have 2 Spark dataframes with same number of columns.

DF1:

```
ID    KEY
1     A
1     A
2     B
3     C
3     C
```

DF2:

```
ID    KEY
1     A
1     A
1     A
2     B
3     C
3     C
4     D
5     E
5     E
```

I want to compare these 2 dataframes and write those records that are there in DF2 but not in DF1.

Expected output:

```
ID    KEY
1     A
4     D
5     E
5     E
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.exceptAll` function.

**`Example:**

```
df1.show()
#+---+---+
#| ID|KEY|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  A|
#|  1|  A|
#|  2|  B|
#|  3|  c|
#|  3|  c|
#+---+---+

df2.show()
#+---+---+
#| ID|KEY|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  A|
#|  1|  A|
#|  1|  A|
#|  2|  B|
#|  3|  c|
#|  3|  c|
#|  4|  D|
#|  5|  E|
#|  5|  E|
#+---+---+

df2.exceptAll(df1).orderBy("ID").show()
#+---+---+
#| ID|KEY|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  A|
#|  4|  D|
#|  5|  E|
#|  5|  E|
#+---+---+
```